# Dynamic Templates passing using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, .net

We have some templates in Exact Target Account. We need send an email to customers using templates. So we need to assign dynamic template to the subscriber. We are implementing code using SOAP API in .NET.

How do we assign a template per email ? Also how do we map the template in ET account and in the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set up different email objects with different templates, and then segment the subscribers by the email you want to send.  You wouldn't be able to switch the email's template dynamically like you describe.

[Here is documentation for the UI](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_email_send_definition/)

[Here is documentation for the API](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_an_email_via_the_web_service_api/) - there is a SOAP envelope that shows how to do this. The specific code portion you would need is here -

```
   <IsHTMLPaste>false</IsHTMLPaste>
   <Template>
      <ID>12345</ID>
   </Template>
```

Use the ID of the template you wish to assign.